# laravel 4 environment setting in fortrabbit with getenev()

Tags: laravel-4, env, fortrabbit

Hi I deploy my application based on laravel 4 to fortrabbit. I try setting local and production environment

in `bootstrap/start.php` I modify

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
        return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

on fortrabbit i define env_var
LARAVEL_ENV to prod

but if i try in fortrabbit

```
php artisan env
```

i obtain local instead of prod

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: How did you define the `LARAVEL_ENV` exactly on Fortrabbit?

Comment: Yes i defined in Fortrabbit dashboard

Comment: If you set/modify a environment variable in the Fortrabbit dashboard, make sure to use a new SSH session to get the new values on the command line.

Comment: to Oliver big thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the environment variable in your Fortrabbit's dashboard, you need to write this in your `start.php` file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    return isset($_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV'])
        ? $_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV']
        : 'prod';
});
```

Note that it is better to fallback to the production environment in case there is no environment variable, since you don't want to mistakenly show debug logs on your production app.

Comment: but this is prod even if I on my localhost, where I havent set LARAVEL_ENV

Comment: Indeed, so you should explicitly set the `LARAVEL_ENV` value to `local` on your local environment. This is of course not obligated, but it may save you from showing debug logs on your production environment one day. If you don't want this, then you can just replace `'prod'` by `'local'` in the above code.